# Decreasing accuracy of a double

Tags: java, android

Everything I find googling around says that either of the following will round a double down to two decimal places.

```
double roundToFourDecimals(double d)
{
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    double myD = Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
    return myD;
}

double nextLon = (double)Math.round(bnextLon * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

But neither works for me.  The value of the double is `3.3743984E7` and the result is the same.
What's wrong?

Comment: Hilariously, I'm assuming this works even as the Double's available 'precision' moves beyond the decimal place.  Does anybody know if there's a cutoff value where the multiplication would produce an effect, but the _division_ wouldn't (obviously, the hundredth's place would be long gone regardless, but...)?

Answer (score 5):

Nothing's wrong. `3.3743984E7` is scientific notation. That is:

```
3.3743984E7 = 3.3743984 * 10^7 = 33743984
```

33,743,984.0 rounded to two decimal places is 33,743,984.0. <s>If, perhaps you specified `33743984.05918`, it would be rounded to `33743984.06`, but both outputs would still say `3.3743984E7`.</s> (The preceding comment has been deleted due to invalidity found by [@Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1267661/sam).)

I [can verify that your rounding code works](http://ideone.com/Hckfod):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double bnextLon = 275914.18410;
        double nextLon = (double) Math.round(bnextLon * 100.0) / 100.0;
        System.out.println(bnextLon + " became " + nextLon);
    }
}
```

> `275914.1841 became 275914.18`

I believe you simply need to determine what value you want in, and what value you want out. The code is giving you exactly what you're specifying.

Comment: Hmm, you updated your answer. While it is still correct, I disagreed with `33743984.06` is `3.3743984E7`. The decimals won't necessarily be rounded off, i.e. `33743984.06` is `3.374398406E7`.

Comment: @Sam Ah, good point. I figured that was the cutoff, but it seems [that's much further down](http://ideone.com/xT7w5l). Will change that.

Comment: Eric: substitute your first instruction with: double bnextLon = 3.1234567E7; and you will see what is happening - it does not round.  If the double is in scientific notation it doesn't work.  I have to figure out how to convert it to decimal notation.  There is a difference in how it is stored in memory.

Comment: @user1058647 No, there isn't. It's not being "stored in scientific notation". The number is represented internally as `31234567.0` (more or less), and when you print it out, it shows it in scientific notation for easier reading. It already *is* rounded.

Comment: Eric, when I run your code with my first instruction it does not round. I'm actually getting the double from a GeoPoint.  There is quite a bit of discussion on this forum and others about how to go about converting a double from sci notation to decimal notation.

Comment: @user1058647 You can believe me or not, it doesn't really matter. The point is that you're rounding a number which is in the magnitude of `10^7`, when it is already rounded. I'll make a last effort to make my point: http://ideone.com/tQYIpn ... if you still don't believe me, I'm afraid there's nothing I can do about that.

Answer (score 2):

`3.3743984E7` means `33743984`, so multiplying by `100` gives `3374398400`, then rounding change nothing, then division goes back.

You should divide by `1E5` then round, than back.